# Casting shadows using a directional light, plane, and cast shadow

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, shadow, arkit

In the WWDC 2017 video, apple explains about a trick to add shadows by using a directional light. Adding a directional light will cast a shadow and adding a plane will show the shadow. But I cannot seem to find mode and colour options of the cast shadow property. I am not looking to do this programatically. So is there any way there is to change the shadow type to Deferred in Xcode?

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/?time=2715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem.... Then this image explains what you are trying to do using `scen view` in Xcode.

You are right, adding plane and directional light with Deferred property will cast shadow. You have to set the x,y and z values of all your `scene` objects accordingly to show this in a proper way.

[image]